# Why are numeric expressions in a FOR loop not expanded by Windows command processor?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I have an issue with a batch script. I made a **FOR** loop in a file and for each line the script should evaluate the expression plus one. The code is:

```
@ECHO ON
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set nmbr=0
REM I already tried set /a nmbr=0
for /f "tokens=3* skip=5" %%a in (dires.txt) do (
    set /a nmbr=!nmbr!+1
    set size!nmbr!=%%a
    set file!nmbr!=%%b
)
echo %file3%
pause
```

But it returned just the expression call, like that:

[image: console error image]

I also tried using `set /a nmbr=%nmbr%+1` instead of `set /a nmbr=!nmbr!+1` but what I got was "0+1" in every loop.

P.S: The file "dires.txt" is a directory list, acquired by doing `dir>dires.txt`

```
 O volume na unidade C nÆo tem nome.
 O N£mero de S‚rie do Volume ‚ 0439-4986

 Pasta de C:\Users\zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz

23/01/2016  20:21                 0 %1
17/01/2016  21:47                 0 %GCDIR
19/02/2016  15:46                 0 dires.txt
17/01/2016  21:47                 0 GCDIR
08/07/2015  16:52                 0 ntuser.dat.LOG2
17/01/2016  21:47                 0 set
04/02/2016  00:45                 4 qwe.txt
23/01/2016  20:23                20 n
08/07/2015  16:52                20 ntuser.ini
20/10/2015  20:56                27 robots.txt
24/08/2015  23:09                36 teste.bat
22/11/2015  21:28                56 massa.txt
22/10/2015  21:55               527 regwizard.log
20/01/2016  20:07               732 lamb.txt
19/02/2016  15:22             1.791 oi.txt
23/01/2016  21:08             2.184 Medir tempo do script.bat
20/01/2016  12:04            55.062 sanct.log
08/07/2015  17:18            65.536 NTUSER.DAT{016888bd-6c6f-11de-8d1d-001e0bcde3ec}.TM.blf
05/10/2015  22:21           165.376 ROFL.EXE
19/02/2016  15:43           262.144 ntuser.dat.LOG1
08/07/2015  17:18           524.288 NTUSER.DAT{016888bd-6c6f-11de-8d1d-001e0bcde3ec}.TMContainer00000000000000000001.regtrans-ms
08/07/2015  17:18           524.288 NTUSER.DAT{016888bd-6c6f-11de-8d1d-001e0bcde3ec}.TMContainer00000000000000000002.regtrans-ms
19/02/2016  15:43         6.553.600 NTUSER.DAT
              23 arquivo(s)      8.155.691 bytes
               0 pasta(s)   420.261.289.984 bytes dispon¡veis
```

Comment: Did it not echo the 3rd file? It worked fine for me. Or are you wondering about why it is showing `!nmbr!` in the set in the output, which is because of the delayedExpansion, but still works. It isn't replaced by the actual value yet because it's expanded **delayed** after showing the commands that get executed.

Comment: The command line in Windows has nothing to do with MS DOS.

Comment: It's not echoing the 3rd file when I call %file3%, that's the problem. I thought the not showing !nmbr! was the issue for that, but apparently it wasn't.

Comment: Do you think it takes more time to post an image or to copy and paste the text from the output?

Comment: I posted an image just for preference, though

Comment: Did you check the contents of dires.txt? Can you show that here too?

Comment: Your code is overly complicated. You can use a basic FOR command to get the file names and the sizes of the files in a directory.

Comment: Here we go: http://textuploader.com/52lqr (dires.txt). @Squashman Please, teach me your way :)

Comment: You're creating file3 inside of a for loop. Echo `!file3!` instead.

Comment: @SomethingDark That's it! I had tried it before without sucess, but now it worked. That's because I was inserting `endlocal` in the wrong place. Thank you all, now it's all working!

Comment: Works perfectly for me. What is "Quick DOS?"

Comment: Seeing as you talk about endlocal, I guess you didn't post the entire script. Note that when you post incomplete scripts, you can't expect a complete answer.

Comment: @Magoo Just a random folder name

Comment: What `endlocal`? How do you expect us to fix code you don't post?

Comment: @Magoo It's already fixed. I didn't posted because I was trying to figure out what I did wrong, making some alterations in the code.

Comment: @Ercnard if I had a dollar for everytime someone did not post all their code because they did not think it was relevant, I would be a millionaire and could retire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe there are only two files listed in your `dires.txt`. Note `findstr` to skip footer from `dir`: change `/C:"File(s)" /C:"Dir(s)"` to your language.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

set "nmbr=0"
for /f "tokens=3* skip=5" %%a in ('
            dir /A:-D /-C ^| findstr /I /V /C:"File(s)" /C:"Dir(s)"
      ') do (
    set /a "nmbr+=1"
    set "size!nmbr!=%%a"
    set "file!nmbr!=%%b"
)
FOR /L %%G in (1, 1, %nmbr%) do echo %%G, !size%%G!, !file%%G!

echo another approach:

set "nmbrx=0"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /B /A:-D 2^>NUL') do (
    set /a "nmbrx+=1"
    set "sizex!nmbrx!=%%~za"
    set "filex!nmbrx!=%%~a"
)
FOR /L %%G in (1, 1, %nmbrx%) do echo %%G, !sizex%%G!, !filex%%G!
```

**Resources** (required reading):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (helpful particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (`%~za` etc. special page) [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)
- (special page) [EnableDelayedExpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)